# Undefined javascript variable using kineticjs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have always thought that if you declared a javascript var outside a function, it would then be available and used within that function if you needed it.

I have a problem with the code below, when I click a button which triggers the get_value function the console tells me that the tween variable is undefined.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            var timeout_val = 0;

            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: 'stage',
                width: 940,
                height: 50
            });
            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

            var line = new Kinetic.Line({
                points: [10, 10, 100, 10],
                stroke: '#FF0000'
            });

            layer.add(line);
            stage.add(layer);

            var xTo = stage.getWidth() - 10;

            var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
                node: line,
                duration: 5,
                points: [10, 10, xTo, 10]
            });
        });

        function get_value(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "players.php",
                data: {}
            }).done(function( result ) {
                if (result != "Timeout Error") {
                    $("#players").html(result);
                }
                $("table").tablesorter({widgets: ["zebra"], sortList: [[1,1], [0,0]]});
                timeout_val = window.setTimeout(get_value, 5000);
            });
            tween.reset();
            tween.play();
        }
    </script>
```

This script block is inside the head of my page if that makes any difference.

I then call the get_value function with a simple input button written like this.

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onClick = "get_value();" />
```

I am at a loss as to why this isn't working, if you could please enlighten me

Thank you
Crouz

Answer (score 1):

`tween` is defined within the inline function used in your call to `$(document).ready`. It is therefore not in scope for `get_value`.

If you defined `get_value` from inside the same `ready` handler, then it would see that variable. Or if you moved `tween` to outside of its `ready` handler so it was global, it would be seen then as well. As it is now, it's in a completely separate scope.

Comment: @JacobThanks so much, I don't know why I didn't see this. I feel like a right idiot now. Thanks buddy.